# How can I write this SQL in R language

Tags: r

How can I convert this query into R.

```
Select Location, MAX(cast(Total_deaths as int)) as TotalDeathCount
From PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths
Where continent is not null 
Group by Location
order by TotalDeathCount desc
```

I tried this but keeping getting an error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
covid_death %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
  select(total_deaths) %>% 
  summarise(TotalDeathCount = max(total_deaths)) %>% 
  filter(continent != null)
```

```
Error in filter(., continent != null) : 
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_filter()`:
! object 'null' not found
```

Comment: `filter(continent != null` --> `filter(!is.na(continent))`, which should already be handled by `drop_na()` (though that will also filter out null values in `Location` and `max(cast(..))`).

Comment: Further issues: your pull is selecting only one column, `total_deaths`, so your last `filter` cannot work since the column has been removed. You likely don't need `select` since you have a `summarize`, but you do need to do something to retain `location` and/or `continent`, such as adding them to a `group_by(continent, location)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do:

```
covid_death          %>%
  drop_na()          %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarise(TotalDeathCount = max(total_deaths)) %>%
  arrange(desc(TotalDeathCount))
```

Comment: I wonder if the OP's use of `filter(continent != null)` means that they expect that column to be included in the results. Perhaps `group_by(continent, location)`?